# change color of combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to color the combobox green under certain circumstances. I only want to color the background of the selected item green. So far, however, it colors the entire combo box. Its also enough if its only changing the text color.[image]

```
<v-combobox
            v-model="key"
            :items="items"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            hide-selected
            return-object
            label="Search script"
            persistent-hint
            :class="{green : BackgroundColor }"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property that returns that classes that you want to attach to your element.

Example:

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    comboboxClass() {
      // assuming you have some prop with a boolean
      return (this.myBoolean) ? {green : BackgroundColor } : undefined;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your template use the computed property:

```
<v-combobox
            v-model="key"
            :items="items"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            hide-selected
            return-object
            label="Search script"
            persistent-hint
            :class="comboboxClass"
        >
```

More information: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application and then use broswer to find the class of the text, overwrite the class.
eg: the className is 'combobox-text'

```css
.combobox-text {
  background: 'green' !important;
}
```